# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type available

Tags: spring-boot

In my spring boot application, i have a service to write on a `txt` file as below:

```
@Service
public class LinksWriterService {

    public LinksWriterService(){
        //..
    }

    public void writeToFile(String text) {
        //..
    }
}
```

and then in my main method i have called it as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

         ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(SeleniumApplication.class, args);
         LinksWriterService writer = context.getBean(LinksWriterService.class);

         writer.writeToFile("Salmaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaan");
    }
```

but in the last line it complains with:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.service.LinksWriterService' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:340)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1090)
    at com.example.demo.SeleniumApplication.main(SeleniumApplication.java:21)
```

Comment: Try to clean and recompile your project .

Comment: this question has nothing to do with writing to a file

Comment: I expect your `LinksWriterService` bean is not being component scanned. Check that the package it's in falls under the component scanning scope declared on your main application class.

Comment: Post your `SeleniumApplication` class

Comment: This is peculiar.  Why are you invoking this from a main method instead of from some other component?  I'm not convinced that it'll wire up at all if you run it through `main`.

Comment: @Makoto i am just checking if my service is functional or not. I am going to write a testcase for it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `SeleniumApplication` class, add a scan annotation and put the relevant package name :

```
@ComponentScan({ "package.where.LinksWriterService.is.located" })
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `@SpringBootApplication` in the class with the main method